# Does timescaledb index works the same as postgreSQL?

Tags: performance, indexing, timescaledb

I am testing an PostgreSQL extension named Timescaledb for time series data.
If I read the document of PostgreSQL right, the query for example

```
WHERE x = 'somestring' and timestamp between 't1' and 't2'
```

will work best with index `(x,timestamp)`. And run `EXPLAIN` on that SQL query shows that it works.

When I try the same query on Timescaledb hypertable, which contains same data and without index `(x,timestamp)`. The performance is about the same (if not better). After creating index `(x,timestamp)`, the performance does not improve.

I understand that the hypertable have a build-in timestamp index. So, I should have a different strategy to add index to the table, for example index with just `(x)`. Is that right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few things about how TimescaleDB handles queries:

1. The primary way that time-based queries get improved performance is
   through chunk exclusion.  Data is partitioned by time into chunks so
   that when a query for a particular time range is executed, the
   planner can ignore chunks that have data outside of that time range.
   Indexes are then applied for chunks that are being searched.

   If you are searching a time-range that includes all chunks, chunk
   exclusion does not apply, and so you get query times closer to
   standard PostgreSQL.
2. If your query matches on a large number of the rows in the chunks
   being scanned, the query planner may choose a sequential scan
   instead of an index scan to save on I/O operations
   https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues/317.
3. There is nothing inherently special about the built-in indexes, you can drop the indexes after hypertable creation or turn them off when running `create_hypertable` (see [timescale api docs](http://docs.timescale.com/v0.9/api#create_hypertable)).